# trying to get image in gallery of images to expand on click

Tags: angularjs, html, image

Trying to get selected clicked image to expand in a gallery of images. I have the expanding working but it only works on the first image in the sets. If I click on another image in the set the first one is the one that gets expanded

```
    <div ng-repeat="album in albumData|filter:q" id="thumbWrapper">
            <h1>{{album.id}}</h1> 
            <h2 ng-click="showme = !showme">{{album.title}}</h2>
            <div id="thumbList"ng-show="showme"class="albumContent">
                <ul ng-controller="PhotoCtrl" id="thumbList">
                    <li ng-repeat="photo in photoData" ng-if="album.userId == photo.albumId">
                        <img id="view" ng-click="zoom()" ng-src={{photo.url}}>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here's my angular js code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AlbumCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums").then(function(response) {
        $scope.albumData = response.data;
        console.log($scope.albumData);
    });
});
app.controller('PhotoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(function(response) {
        $scope.photoData = response.data;
        $scope.zoom = function() {
        var imageId = document.getElementById('view');
        if(imageId.style.width == "1000px"){
        imageId.style.width = "600px";
        imageId.style.height = "600px";
        }else{
        imageId.style.width = "1000px";
        imageId.style.height = "1000px";  
        }
    };
        // console.log($scope.photoData);
    });
});
```

any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the image id unique for each img tag

```
<img id="view{{$index}}" ng-click="zoom($index)" ng-src={{photo.url}}>
```

pass the index as parameter to the function

```
$scope.zoom = function(index) {
        var elem = "view" + index;
        var imageId = document.getElementById(elem);
        if (imageId.style.width == "1000px") {
            imageId.style.width = "600px";
            imageId.style.height = "600px";
        } else {
            imageId.style.width = "1000px";
        }

}
```

and put the zoom function out side of the http request

Comment: hi im getting this error when click fires after using this code: ReferenceError: index is not defined
    at b.$scope.zoom (album.js:15)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:239), <anonymous>:4:210)
    at e (angular.min.js:284)
    at b.$eval (angular.min.js:148)
    at b.$apply (angular.min.js:149)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:284)
    at hg (angular.min.js:39)
    at HTMLImageElement.d (angular.min.js:39)

Comment: did you pass the index parameter to the function in both html and js

Comment: yes I did this in my html: <img id="view{{$index}}" ng-click="zoom($index)" ng-src={{photo.url}}> and js:  $scope.zoom = function() {
        var elem = "view" + index;
        var imageId = document.getElementById('elem');
        if (imageId.style.width == "1000px") {
            imageId.style.width = "600px";
            imageId.style.height = "600px";
        } else {
            imageId.style.width = "1000px";
        }
    };

Comment: and js like this `$scope.zoom = function(index) {`

Comment: OH! nope didn't do that haha trying now :)

Comment: hey getting a type error now: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at b.$scope.zoom (album.js:17)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:1), <anonymous>:4:210)
    at e (angular.js:26994)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:18161)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:18261)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26999)
    at hg (angular.js:3734)
    at HTMLImageElement.d (angular.js:3722)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14525
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11008
$apply @ angular.js:18266
(anonymous) @ angular.js:26999
hg @ angular.js:3734
d @ angular.js:3722

Comment: try to change the html like this `<img id="{{ 'view' + $index }}" ng-click="zoom($index)" ng-src={{photo.url}}>`

Comment: hey just switched the 'view' in the {{}} and the same error occurs when click fires

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: change `var imageId = document.getElementById('elem');` to `var imageId = document.getElementById(elem);`

Comment: oh wow, can't believe that slipped by me! String instead of variable haha. it works now thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Zohranio no prob

Comment: hey sorry to bring this up again, but I just realized that this only applies the enlargening to the first album set. Even if I click on an image to enlarge on say the second album the corresponding index for the first album will be enlarged not the clicked one. Not sure why this is happening =/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this directory. Just copy and paste this code in the app.js and css code in style.css. But be careful, this applies to all images in your website

```
.directive('img', function ($window) {
    'use strict';

    function getElementOffset (element) {
        var de = document.documentElement;
        var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        var top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - de.clientTop;
        var left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - de.clientLeft;
        return { top: top, left: left };
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var expanded = false,
                cloned = element.clone(true),
                offset = getElementOffset(element[0]);
            cloned.addClass('large');
            cloned.attr('src', attr.src);
            cloned.css('top', offset.top + 'px');
            cloned.css('left', offset.left + 'px');
            cloned.bind('click', function () {
                if (expanded) {
                    cloned.removeClass('expanded');
                    expanded = false;
                } else {
                    cloned.addClass('expanded');
                    expanded = true;
                }
            });
            element.parent().append(cloned);
            angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
                if (expanded) {
                    cloned.removeClass('expanded');
                    expanded = false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
.app img {
display: block;
float: right;
width: 200px;
}

.app img.large {
cursor: -moz-zoom-in; 
cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; 
cursor: zoom-in;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.app img.expanded {
cursor: -moz-zoom-out; 
cursor: -webkit-zoom-out; 
cursor: zoom-out;
left: 0 !important;
top: 0 !important;
width: 100%;
}
```

source: https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/jwtj57kt/